# Сравнение в java

Tags: java

Всем привет, помогите решить проблему. Вот этот код выводит все названия файлов из определенной папки (к сожалению, нет такой штуки выделить код, а может есть - я слепой):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileFinder {

    public static List<String> getFileNames(File directory, String extension) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        File[] total = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : total) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(extension)) {
                list.add(file.getName());
            }
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                List<String> tempList = getFileNames(file, extension);
                list.addAll(tempList);          
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        List<String> files = getFileNames(new File("C:\\Users\\vany\\Desktop\\dirdir"), "txt");
        for (String string : files) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

А как мне сравнить имя какого-то файла (которая программа выводит) с вот этим:

```
File file = new File("C:\\hello.txt");
String fileName= file.getName(); 
System.out.println("The File is "+fileName);
```

Исправленная версия,код будет таким.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

  public class FileFinder {

public static List<String> getFileNames(File directory, String extension) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] total = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : total) {
        if (file.getName().endsWith(extension)) {
            list.add(file.getName());
        }
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            List<String> tempList = getFileNames(file, extension);
            list.addAll(tempList);          
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C:\\hello.txt");
    String fileName = file.getName(); 
    System.out.println("The File is " + fileName);

    List<String> files = getFileNames(new File("C:\\Users\\ваня\\Desktop\\txt"), "txt");
    for (String string : files) {

        System.out.println(string);
        if (fileName.equals(string)) { 
            System.out.println("Hello word");  
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Уважаемы модераторы,прошу извинить за форматирование,просто не знаю как это делать справку прочитал,добавил <pre>,а все-равно-коряво.

Comment: @ваняя, не надо `<pre>`, надо кнопку `101010` нажать )

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/1984/nofate спасибо

Comment: @Nofate еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (filename.equals(anotherFilename)) { 
  ....
}
```

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, прокомментировать, где что?

Comment: Или это код сразу сравнивает?Я просто недавно начал java изучать.

Comment: `filename` и `anotherFilename` - имена файлов (типа `String`), которые вы сравниваете. Порядок не важен в вашем случае. Если строки равны, `equals()` вернет `true` и выполнится выражение в фигурных скобках.

Comment: гигантское спасибо)

Comment: кстати, у меня ошибка вылезает,когда я добавляю ваш код,если можно я выложу фото.

Comment: Должно быть примерно так:
    
    File file = new File("C:\\hello.txt");
    String fileName = file.getName(); 
    System.out.println("The File is " + fileName);

    List<String> files = getFileNames(new File("C:\\Users\\ваня\\Desktop\\txt"), "txt");
    for (String string : files) {

        System.out.println(string);
        if (filename.equals(string)) { 
            System.out.println("Hello word");  
        }
    }